# If I send a signed email, how does the end user get the public key?

Tags: public-key

I am sending a signed email using Python and smtplib. I have successfully signed the email using this example: http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/svn/ndg-security/branches/Dependencies/m2crypto/doc/howto.smime.html

My question is how does the end user get the public key to check the signature? I have not seen any examples of attaching the public key to the same email. Thanks.

Comment: usually, using a certificate that is attached to e-mail or via out-of-band means.

Comment: Check the section `Sign and Encrypt` from that web page. You need the recipient's pubkey in order to send him a message. And the receiver needs your pubkey in order to check your signature.

Comment: yea, but how do they get it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-should-i-distribute-my-public-key

Answer (score 3):

You can send the public key certificate as an attachment with the email or you can send the public key certificate in a separate email.

The main point is the end-user should receive the public key for verification.

A certificate can be a file e.g. *.cer . The end user needs to have a program to verify the document.

UPDATE:
Chances of an MIM attack or other attacks always exist. But having more than one form independent communication can help the situation along. E.g. send the key in soft form (usb/CD) with a courier service. Or talk to the person you send your public key to and ask them to open the key in a text editor and tally first and the last line of the key. Or use public key database/storage providers like PGP does.

Comment: I think this is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. How does the receiver know the public key actually belongs the sender?

Comment: @DaanBakker chances of an MIM attack or other attacks always exist. But having more than one form Independent communication can help the situation along. E.g. send the key in soft form (usb/CD) with a courier Service. Or talk to the person you send your public key to and ask them to open the key in a text editor and tally first and the last line of the key.

Comment: I think that is what this answer should be: only use an independent secure communication channel. If you send the public key through the same channel it entirely defeats the purpose of the signature.

Comment: @DaanBakker S/MIME and CMS use X.509 certificates, and the whole purpose of X.509 certificates is to be secure even when distributed over insecure channels -- if (all) the CAs (always) act correctly,  admittedly an assumption not always satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be about S/MIME only, although there are other kinds of signed email, notably PGP.

S/MIME is internally CMS and [CMS SignedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.1) contains a `certificates` field that can and normally does include the **signer's certificate**. In particular, OpenSSL includes the signer's cert by default, and the example signed message on that page does have it:

```
# note: -verify -noverify means verify the data signature using the cert,
# but don't try to verify the cert itself, which would fail because 
# this cert is selfsigned and not under a root that we trust (or should)
$ openssl base64 -d <temp.b64 \
| openssl cms -inform d -verify -noverify -out /dev/null -certsout temp.crt \
; openssl2 x509 <temp.crt -text
Verification successful
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=SG, O=M2Crypto, CN=S/MIME Sender/emailAddress=sender@example.dom
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 31 11:40:33 2001 GMT
            Not After : Mar 31 11:40:33 2002 GMT
        Subject: C=SG, O=M2Crypto, CN=S/MIME Sender/emailAddress=sender@example.dom
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e5:ce:53:8f:50:87:4d:23:b1:6b:5a:b6:ab:41:
                    58:8b:03:16:60:7a:6d:26:92:5c:be:d6:66:53:0a:
                    e0:53:9b:07:ac:0f:0e:9c:23:34:70:35:c4:8f:42:
                    8f:7f:77:1f:36:31:df:7c:1f:07:58:cc:c8:e1:41:
                    20:36:61:57:40:db:31:a0:66:7e:8a:ac:31:2e:53:
                    63:cb:d3:21:ed:e1:56:fc:18:ea:e6:13:57:6e:8b:
                    92:95:0d:2b:58:14:64:a3:15:7a:e3:2f:ad:ea:54:
                    1e:85:bd:f6:59:f6:17:41:b2:85:c4:52:52:5f:34:
                    b1:3b:1d:d1:f1:88:52:3d:dd
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                5C:EC:A8:94:BD:6D:E2:36:81:C1:91:51:33:B3:12:F2:70:4B:CD:4A
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:5C:EC:A8:94:BD:6D:E2:36:81:C1:91:51:33:B3:12:F2:70:4B:CD:4A
                DirName:/C=SG/O=M2Crypto/CN=S/MIME Sender/emailAddress=sender@example.dom
                serial:00

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
         7a:37:0e:b0:87:47:ce:9f:49:35:40:bd:f8:97:75:2b:30:5a:
         a2:ad:08:48:54:1d:17:42:4c:b1:46:97:88:43:93:61:b2:67:
         16:85:ba:a6:70:89:44:73:fc:7e:e7:32:27:32:98:8d:b0:93:
         3f:07:ff:0c:87:16:0f:06:dc:12:1e:85:44:69:8f:6b:ff:65:
         65:d8:7a:8b:db:81:2e:c4:64:02:d5:56:40:e3:e2:13:65:fc:
         82:07:59:de:86:b6:fd:54:38:37:fb:51:16:f1:b6:5d:e1:43:
         df:de:4d:62:13:ad:e7:d3:d6:17:ae:3e:76:ab:f1:cc:f2:76:
         c3:8b
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In real usage, you need to use a cert from a CA trusted by your recipient(s), which might be

- a public CA like Comodo or a more local one like a (common) employer, a (common?) country government or government agency, a (common?) bank, etc.

  If this CA uses intermediate certs, also commonly called chain certs, as all(?) public CAs do, those should be included in the message; [OpenSSL allows you to specify these](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/CMS_sign.html) and [M2crypto wraps OpenSSL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) but I don't see detailed doc anyplace obvious.
- a CA that you set up for yourself and the recipient(s), or one of them does for you